# Using AngularJS directives and $scope independently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, compatibility

A bit of background first:

Up until recently I have been working mostly on lightweight, single page Angular applications, but in the last couple days started working on a new Tapestry+Backbone project. And it feels ***cumbersome***.

Just disabling a button whether a checkbox is checked or not leads to a labyrinthine nightmare of properties and functions and calls, where it could be solved by a simple ng-if.

I realize it might be a poor habit, and my programming skills are far from being the best, but having access to good old ng-if, ng-repeat, ng-class, would really help the process. On the other hand, I don't have the option to rebuild the whole app as an Angular app.

**Is there a way to add Angular directives and $scope methods to a non-Angular project? Can this cause compatibility issues?**

Comment: `ng-app` can simply go on any element. Put angular where you need it.

Comment: angular can be run as a "silo", where every page is it's own angular app.  however, this essentially means that you don't use the routing/SPA aspects of angular, and each page transition involves reloading all of your angular variables, which may or may not be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to add angular directives, the app must be bootstrapped and injected into the system and angular will work.  Angular was designed to work as needed basis.  However, architecturally, this is not recommended.

`ng-app` and `app.js` to start the app and everything, minus some of the SPA features of the app, should work.

Here's an example with jQuery and Angular:

http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html